# Teams custom app update not propagated to users and store

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

I have a problem updating a custom app in Microsoft Teams (scope "personal"). I changed the manifest (added some tabs, increased the version, kept the app-id).
I uploaded the new package in the Teams admin center under [https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/policies/manage-apps/{app-id}](https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/policies/manage-apps/%7Bapp-id%7D)

In Teams admin center I can now see the increased version number and description. The app is shown as published and allowed to be used. Also I have no pending approvals. But when I open my personal custom app in the Teams client or browser the app is not updated. (Old version number, old description,...). Same in the store under "Apps developed for your organization". Old version, old description.

I already put the app-package through the validator and everything was perfect. I also waited >24 hours and now am out of ideas where to look.

Any suggestions how I can get my updated app?

Ben

Comment: How did you install the app originally? Through the company store, or through App Studio?

Comment: I’m sorry, but I don’t remember. It’s been over a year ago. Would this have any impact?

Comment: Also deleting and re-installing the app isn’t an option, because the app was rolled out to ~1600 user by policy and the effects are unclear

Comment: After thinking about your question, I think it was published through app studio.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the chat above, I think the issue is you kind of have two "duplicate" deployments of the app - one deployed through App Studio, and one deployed through the "company store". If you just want, simply, to update your app, then do it through App Studio - either *make the changes there* and redeploy, or DELETE your app in App Studio and re-import using the new manifest (then redeploy from there). Alternatively, if you want to test the "normal user" install/update cycle, then DELETE the app installation itself (right click the app in the left menu and uninstall), then delete the app in the Admin centre, install the old version into there, install it for the user, test the upgrade, etc. (bit of a business). Basically, this is why to have a separate 'Dev tenancy' :-).

On that note, if your company is a Microsoft Partner, you might have access to multiple temporary test tenants.

Comment: Thanks for hinting me back to app studio. I tried to publish it from there and separately approved it in teams admin center. We'll see what happens.

Comment: ok great. One of those should definitely work - let me know. App Studio update should be instant...

Comment: I put a full answer here because there's more space, but also so others in future can find it, if it ends up being helpful for this

Comment: I published it through app studio, then approved it. I was to eager and could not wait for the automatic update and manually uninstalled and installed it for my acocunt. This was the first time, it worked for this user. So thanks a lot. Next thing, I hoped the update will be properly pushed to the other users.

Comment: Just curious: Why is there a difference between uploading and publishing the package in app studio and publishing it from Teams admin center?

Comment: ok glad it's working. App Studio is direct, immediate installation, but only for that one user (it's really a developer tool, so not -meant- to be used, or needed, by end users).

Comment: Ok. Installing from AppStudio did not work. Publishing did... Anyways thank you very much for you help and have a great 2021. :-)

Comment: strange...just a delay in the publishing, maybe?